# Qml Canvas мультипоточное рисование

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, многопоточность, qml

Возможно ли использовать объект context у Canvas на различных потоках?

Нашел такой простой пример:

```
var offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.postMessage({ canvas: offscreen }, [offscreen]);
```

Однако в Qml Canvas я не нашел аналога  "transferControlToOffscreen", чтобы реализовать нечто подобное с помощью WorkerScript.
Есть ли возможность как-то организвать многопоточку для рисования на Canvas в qml?

Comment: Выносить рисование canvas в другой поток в браузере не сильно вижу смысла. А логика да, можно вынести, чтобы она в отдельном потоке выполнялась

Comment: Если нужно что-то делать эффективно по производительности, то нужно рисовать не на 2D canvas, а на webgl canvas